# Is it possible to match all subdirectories by a PageRoute or convention in Razor pages?

Tags: razor, razor-3

I'd like to use same page for all subdirectories in Razor pages.
I have this in startup:

```
services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
  options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/test", "{path?}");
});
```

But this only matches first subdirectory, such as test/my. Is it possible to match "test/my/many/wishes" and similar requests?

I'd like to avoid url rewriting, as I *think* using the routing approach then also helps with link formatting etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know, it's a basic one. But I couldn't find it at first - here it is for root:

```
options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("/index", "{*url}");
```

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/routing